# Upgrade Angular 12 to 13 - Compile error in mjs file

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

We are trying to upgrade our angular from 12 to 13 with node 14.15.0 and facing the below error while giving npm start

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '..\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/platform-browser.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '..\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2015/router.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '..\@angular\router\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/compiler' in '..\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '..\node_modules\@angular\common\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '..\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/platform-browser.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '..\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2015'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2015/router.mjs

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '..\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser' in '..\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\fesm2015'

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^13.2.3",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@juggle/resize-observer": "^3.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^4.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.3.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.0.7",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.9.0",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.2",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mat-currency-format": "0.0.7",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-restangular": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^8.0.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "sass": "^1.45.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.2.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^8.3.20",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.2",
    "@types/angular": "^1.6.57",
    "@types/angular-animate": "^1.5.10",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/angular-resource": "^1.5.15",
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/angular-sanitize": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.9",
    "@types/google.analytics": "^0.0.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.14.1",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "canonical-path": "^1.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "gsap": "^3.7.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "ng2-odometer": "^1.1.3",
    "ngx-countdown": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-modialog": "^5.0.1",
    "null-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup": "^1.27.11",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^6.0.4",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.4",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.2"
  }
}
```

Please someone suggest me.

Comment: try to deleting node_module folder and angain in type reinstall it using `npm i`

Comment: Tried by deleting node_module and reinstall using npm i but still facing the same error

Comment: Hey, have you got solution for this. I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, can you share the project? so we can solve together the problem

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46795 there is an issue related. Try to update also the webpack to version 5 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Also in angular 12, the path mentioned in the above error had js file but after upgrading to 13, it is coming as mjs file

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to custom webpack config .
**Please attach the code related to your custom webpack config in here .** One of the ways to fix this can be to add your `mjs` rule to your custom config .

```
    {
      test: /\.mjs$/,
      include: /node_modules/,
      type: "javascript/auto"
    }
```

If that does not work , you may have to make appropriate changes to upgrade the webpack libraries to a higher version (webpack 5).

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I was also facing multiple dependency conflicts while updating Angular version from 11 to 14. I even tried deleting package lock, but there were still conflicting dependencies. I also used `npm i` with `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`, but nothing worked.

In the end, I followed these steps below and it finally worked.

1. Make a list of all of the additional libraries that you have added, and remove these from your `package.json` file.
2. Delete your `package-lock.json` and do `npm i` one more time.
3. Now, run the following command to update Angular:

   ```
   ng update @angular/cli@^<major_version> @angular/core@^<major_version>
   ```
4. Once done, install the additional dependencies that you have added one-by-one and only install the latest version.
5. You might need to update your TypeScript version too.

Now, I don't know if this is the best way or not, but only this approach worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be Node v14? I upgraded from Angular 12 to Angular 13 while also updating Node to v16. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This could be a nodejs issue, you probably need to add an entry
`"type": "module"` in your `package.json` file

check this thread for details:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20785

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to have a clean install of the packages without package-lock.json present in your folder.

angular-cli has as well some folder linking with your global packages, so I'm assuming as well that your global @angular/angular-cli is corrupted.

From my understanding, when you attempt to run your Angular project for the first time after installation, there's will be a compilation process of the Angular libraries and for some reason, your packages fail to exist or have a correct build